# Why does $\sum a_i \exp(b_i)$ always have root?

Tags: abstract-algebra, complex-analysis

Let $z$ be complex.
Let $a_i,b_i$ be polynomials of $z$ with real coefficients.
Also the $a_i$ are non-zero and the non-constant parts of the polynomials $b_i$ are distinct.

Let $j > 1$.

$$f(z) = \sum_{i=1}^j a_i \exp(b_i)$$

It seems there always exists a complex value $s$ such that

$$ f(s) = 0$$

Is this true?
If so, why? 
How to prove this? If false, what are the simplest counter-examples?

Comment: Have you left off some constraints?  Why not take $a_1 = 1 = a_2$ and $b_1 = z = b_2$ ?

Comment: Trying to guess what constraints you might have had in mind...only thing I can think of is "the $b_i$'s are not all the same".  Just adding constraints on the degrees doesn't rule out cheap counterexamples.

Comment: Even then you can get counterexamples like $a_1=a_2=1,b_1=z,b_2=z+1$.

Comment: @KlausDraeger I suggest to add the condition $b_i(0)=0$ because any constant term can be replaced with a nonzero factor of $a_i$.

Comment: Indeed you can.  We want independence between the $b_i$'s (and constants).

Comment: I edited. You guys were right. I solved the issue differently by considering the nonconstant parts of polynomials. See edit. Hope everything clear. Thanks for the useful comments.

Comment: I think the title should say "Why does ... always have a root?"

Comment: @ rahul yes and no. Technically yes. But i think it makes the reader more curious in its present form ? Sorry if thats immoral or something.

Comment: I think you should be able to prove this inductively using Liouvilles theorem if you assume each $a_i$ are non-constant. Define $f_1 = a_1(z)\exp[b_1(z)]$, which is entire, and has a zero thanks to the fundamental theorem of algebra. Then define $f_k(z) = g(z) + a_k(z)\exp[b_k(z)]$ for $g(z)$ entire, which means $f_k$ is also entire. If you suppose this is never zero, then $1/f_k$ is a bounded entire function; hence there is a constant $\delta$ such that $f_k(z) = \delta$ for all $z$. I'm not too sure where to go from here, maybe someone else can see where it goes.

Comment: I think not. If a function is not zero its inverse is not bounded. Example exp(x) and exp(-x).

Comment: Two minor remarks: 1) it is not a good idea to chain negations, especially when you think of non-native English speakers who might read your question: "there are no solutions such there does not exist" makes me dizzy; 2) you have placed a "(*)" symbol that doesn't refer to anything - is there anything missing from your question?

Comment: The (*) is irrelavant now. I take note of the comments.

Comment: Under the current constraints, I get the counterexample $a_1 = 1$, $a_2 = -1$, $b_1 = z^2 - z$, and $b_2 = z^2-3z+2$.  The zero occurs at the obvious place, the shared root of $b_1$ and $b_2$, $z = 1$.  Perhaps you really want to require that the $b_i$ are relatively prime?  (Or perhaps there is one negation too many in the statement and I'm turned around?)

Comment: The conjecture ( now Proved ) was that we always get a zero. So no counterexample @ Eric Towers.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This follows from the theory of entire functions of finite order
in complex analysis.  Specifically, we have:

*Proposition*:
Suppose $f(z) = \sum_{i=1}^j a_i \exp b_i$ for some polynomials $a_i,b_i$
(which may have complex coefficients, though the question specifies
real polynomials).  Then if $f\,$ has no complex zeros then there exists
a polynomial $P$ such that $f = \exp P$.

*Proof*: let $d = \max_i\max(\deg a_i,\deg b_i)$.  If $d \leq 0$ then $f$ is constant
and we may choose for $P$ a constant polynomial.  Else there exists
a constant $A$ such that $\left|\,f(z)\right| \leq \exp(A\left|z\right|^d)$
for all complex $z$.  This makes $f$ an
[entire
function of order at most $d$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entire_function#Order_and_type).
If $f$ has no zeros then $f = e^g$ for some analytic function $g$,
and it follows that $g$ is a polynomial (by a special case of the 
Hadamard product for an entire function of finite order). $\Box$

Moreover, once we put the expansion $f(z) = \sum_{i=1}^j a_i \exp b_i$
in normal form by assuming that each $b_i$ vanishes at zero
(else subtract $b_i(0)$ from $b_i$ and multiply $a_i$ by $e^{b_i(0)}$),
then at least one of the $b_i$ is $P-P(0)$, and we can cancel and
combine terms to identify $f$ with $\exp P$.  The proof (by considering
behavior for large $|z|$) is somewhat tedious, though much easier in
the real case [hint: start by writing $f(z) \, / \exp P(z)$ as 
$\sum_{i=1}^j a_i \exp (b_i-P)$].  In particular, if $j>1$ and
no two $b_i$ differ by a constant then $f$ cannot equal $\exp P$
and thus must have complex zeros.

Comment: Thanks Noam !  Just one thing, how do we find the polynomial P ?? I assume the degree of P is exactly d. But how to find the coëfficiënts for P ?? Thanks. I accepted but hope you adress this too. +1 !

Comment: I think I addressed this in the last paragraph.  If $j>1$, all the $a_i$ are nonzero, and all the $b_i$ are distinct even modulo constants, then there are bound to be complex zeros, so there is no $P$.  In general,   normalize so each $b_i(0)=0$ and combine like terms (terms with the same $b_i$); you must get a single term $a \exp b$ for some scalar $a \neq 0$ and some polynomial $b$, and then $P=b+\log a$.

Comment: The last paragraph is a special case of a much stronger result of Borel. If $b_i(z)$ are entire functions (not necessarily polynomials) which are distinct modulo constants, then $\sum \exp f_i(z) \neq 0$. This result recently came up in a question I just answered: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1349495

Comment: Nice answer for 1349495, but the result here doesn't seem to be quite a special case of Borel's theorem because of the polynomial factors $a_i$.

Comment: I got a warning my bounty is about to expire. But I already accepted ?

Comment: I do not understand the proof for the proposition and have several questions. Let me ask them one by one. $d = \max_i \deg a_i$,  $d \leq 0 \implies \text{ all } a_i$ are constant. How do we conclude $f$ is constant, as $b_i$'s can be non-constant polynomials which makes $f$ non-constant?

Comment: @ Hans , yes but we know from algebra that a nonconstant polynomial equation always has a zero.

Comment: I think you are confused Hans. It helped me to think about Large z.

Comment: @mick: Yes, indeed I am confused. What you said about nonconstant polynomial equation always having a zero was true. But I do not see how this relates to my question which concerns with the proof in Noam D. Elkies' proof of his proposition. How does $a_i$ being constant lead to $f=\sum_{i=1}^j \exp(b_i)$ being constant when $b_i$'s are non-constant polynomials?

Comment: There is a typo in the proof of the proposition, which causes my confusion. Instead of $d = \max_i \deg a_i$ being the maximal degree of $a_i$'s only, $d$ should be the maximal degree of all of $a_i$ and $b_i$'s, or $d= \max_i \max(\deg a_i,\deg b_i)$. I am edit the answer pending @NoamD.Elkies's concurrence.

Comment: Yes there was an error, but the intention was $\max_i \deg b_i$ (it's OK to include the $\deg a_i$ too but not necessary).  Sorry for the error.